# Please check my board design before I waste money

Tags: arduino, pcb, pcb-design, schematics, led-strip

TL;DR: Please make sure my schematic and board design won't blow up on me. [GitHub Repo](https://github.com/theChosenSasquatch/bluetooth_led_driver) if you're feeling extra thorough.

## Project overview

I am trying to create an Arduino based Bluetooth RGB led controller, but larger-scale than most. I'm planning on having 25 meters of (common-anode) 12v led strips, which means about 300 watts of lights. I'm using a scavenged Corsair CX430M for power, and as a housing for the Arduino.
[image: My proposed schematic]
I've already programmed the [ESP32](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/13907) brain and set up the circuit using a single RGB led with transistors instead of MOSFETs, and resistors between the emitter and ground. I don't know how closely that performance will translate to my PCB setup.

## Main Schematic concerns

1: I've read that the 2 resistors before the MOSFETs will reduce accidental switching from trace capacitance or something. Regardless, If something is overkill or dangerously underkill, please let me know.

2: I've selected [NCE3080KA](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/szlcsc/Wuxi-NCE-Power-Semiconductor-NCE3080KA_C152149.pdf) MOSFETs. I think I can use just about any MOSFET, but if this one is wrong for some reason please let me know. Right now the PWM is set for a 5kHz, but I'm pretty sure I go much lower. GPIO voltage is 3.3.

[image: Proposed PCB Layout]
sorry for the bad screenshot. I'm not sure what layers should be visible. The full board design is available [here](https://github.com/theChosenSasquatch/bluetooth_led_driver)

## Main PCB concerns

1: The PCB will be passing up to maybe 30 amps of current. To mitigate the issue, I added a stupid amount of vias to help sink heat and left the entire bottom solder mask-free, but I'm not sure if that's sufficient.

2: Manufacturability. Is something wrong with my design that just won't work, or can't be made for some reason?

**Edit 1: ** @WesleyLee pointed out that I switched the mosfet drain and source. Updated pictures to reflect changes.

Comment: What’s your Vcc voltage? What is your switching frequency?

Comment: The biggest problem you have is that you are feeding 10A of current into long LED strips.  The traces and wiring on those strips aren't usually made for high current.  You may find that the far end of each strip is darker than the near end - or doesn't light at all.  Worst case, the traces burn off of the LED strips from the high current.

Comment: Manually carve up some copper clad to build one copy of the amplifier and try it.  You should probably re-place things so that the FETs are in a different area surrounding by copper pours, and the through hole ESP is elsewhere.  I'd even consider making distinct little PCBs handling one channel each, at least for the initial test.

Comment: I think you flipped the Drain and Source.

Comment: @winny, LED voltage is 12V. Arduino runs off the 5v rail. the switching freq is configurable, but I was planning on 5kHz.

Comment: @JRE, I know that that is definitely a possibility. if necessary I may parallel a few strips, using wire extensions.  hopefully it wont be that bad though.

Comment: @WesleyLee as in I connected the wrong pins in the schematic, or I made the eagle part wrong?

Comment: Your symbol and footprint are correct/consistent. You flipped them on the schematic so on the board its also flipped: the large tab is Drain, which should be connected to the LED strips, not GND. A good reference is the body diode on the FET.

Comment: @WesleyLee Thank you. I've updated the pictures and github repo. Am I correct in thinking that, with the way I had it, the lights would always be full white due to the diode in the fets?

Comment: Good. At 30 A you will burn 9 W in your MOSFET. What’s your cooling situation?

Comment: @winny I never really thought about it. I'm prepared to strap a steel plate under the board to help, but those mosfets are currently being completely covered by the arduino. How big of a heatsink is required for 10W? There will be a 120mm fan blowing over everything.

Comment: Not enough. You need 3 K/W or lower. Look at existing heat sinks to get a feeling for how large they are to get to 3 K/W. If you place a hurricane wind over it, it will be about 5 times better. Loud fan about 3 times better. Silent fan about 2 times better. Use better MOSFETs?

Comment: With reversed Drain/Source, the LEDs would be on until the body diodes die - which might be super quick depending on the current. :)

Comment: @winny Alright the cooling solution I've come up with is an nvme heatsink with an integrated fan. Should fit perfectly underneath the Arduino. I'm on mobile, so bad formatting, but this is the one I bought. M.2 Nvme Cooler Heatsinks with 20mm PWM Fan， for Solid State Drive on The Computer https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07QZQZ422

Comment: Do you get 4 K/W or lower with it? Why not spend your money on better silicon?

Comment: @winny. To be honest, Its because I foolishly purchased the components by the time I read your suggestion. It was a really dumb move, but I hadn't even though about heat generation. If it breaks, I'll just make another, I guess, with better fets.

Comment: It’s very good to learn from your mistakes! My old tutor once told me, the price of aluminum and copper will only go up but the price of silicon is bound to go down. He does however make low volume industrial and military stuff where you don’t need to consider the price so he uses the best devices available on the market. He does have a point though - when it is better to spend all the money for fans, heatsinks and the like on just better silicon in the first place?